Android Firebase Carshlytics custom keys do not show if set in startup initializer
My current android project uses Firebase crashlytics for crash reporting.
i am attempting to add signed in user related custom keys on app startup that would be available if and when a crash occurs.
im setting the custom keys as follows once the user is successfully signed in
Firebase.crashlytics.setUserId(user.id.toString())

Firebase.crashlytics.setCustomKeys {
       key("isSomething", loggedInUser.isSomething)
       key("isWhatever", loggedInUser.isWhatever)
}

these custom keys never show in the firebase crashlytics console when later force a crash later within my application.
however when i set custom keys just before i force the same crash the custom keys are listed.
heres the code for the forced crash:-
    Firebase.crashlytics.setCustomKeys {
        key("str_key", "hello")
        key("bool_key", true)
        key("int_key", 1)
        key("long_key", 1L)
        key("float_key", 1.0f)
        key("double_key", 1.0)
    }

    if (true) throw RuntimeException("Test Crash") // Force a crash

why are the custom keys i set up earlier in my application not showing in the crashlytics console?
